# How can I "force" SharePoint list data to populate in my Power Automate Flow using a Formula Expression?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-list

I know that Dynamic expressions can be finicky at the best of times (and I'm absolutely ready to accept that there is something I'm forgetting here) but there is data that is not showing up when I try to add it to my workflow:

Missing Department Data

[image]

I know there is a way to "force" data into those field using an expression, but for the life of me I cannot remember how to do that. If anyone can point me in the direction of the proper documentation for that it would be VERY much appreciated. I don't think I'm phrasing any of this correctly. Or at the very least, If someone could explain to me why my "Department" column is not showing up (it is a single text column in the SharePoint list) with the rest of the options.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, because you haven’t explained this, but when the flow is manually triggered, you enter a whole bunch of information and department is one of those fields, is that right? And you problem is, department doesn’t show up as dynamic content in your list to choose from. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. Sorry my explanation wasn't clear

Comment: Can you provide the trigger JSON? If you don’t know how to find it, go to a successful run and click on the inputs and outputs of the trigger. Update and put that on your question if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the dynamic property isn't showing up.  Regardless though, you should still be able to get the value of the relevant parameter.

This is an example of the run log for a manually pushed button.

[image: Run]

If you hit the `Show raw outputs` button, you'll get the JSON that's generated and passed through from the trigger to the flow.

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
        "Accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
        "Accept-Language": "en-au",
        "Expect": "100-continue",
        "Host": "prod-02.australiasoutheast.logic.azure.com",
        "User-Agent": "Power%20Automate/4.210203.6,CFNetwork/1404.0.5,Darwin/22.3.0",
        "X-MS-APIM-Referrer": "https://australia-001.azure-apim.net/apim/logicflows/masked",
        "x-ms-client-region": "australia",
        "x-ms-flavor": "Production",
        "x-ms-gateway-object-id": "",
        "X-MS-APIM-Referrer-Prefix": "https://australia-001.azure-apim.net/apim/logicflows/88a43aa8-ac75-masked",
        "X-MS-APIM-Callback": "https://australia-001.consent.azure-apim.net",
        "x-ms-user-id": "8ddf4a13-masked",
        "x-ms-user-name": "Joe Bloggs",
        "x-ms-user-name-encoded": "Sm9lIEJsb2dncw==",
        "x-ms-user-email": "joe.bloggs@email.com.au",
        "x-ms-user-email-encoded": "am9lLmJsb2dnc0BlbWFpbC5jb20uYXU=",
        "x-ms-user-timestamp": "2023-04-23T10:07:26.5382614Z",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "",
        "Content-Length": "249",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "user": {
            "displayName": "Joe Bloggs",
            "email": "joe.bloggs@email.com.au"
        },
        "key-button-timestamp": "2023-04-23T20:07:25+10:00",
        "key-button-date": "2023-04-23",
        "text": "Test 1",
        "text_1": "Test 2",
        "text_2": "Option 2",
        "text_3": [
            "Option 2",
            "Option 3"
        ]
    }
}
```

It's *that* JSON that you can use in any expression down the line.

So if you want to retrieve the `key-button-date` property, you would use this expression ...

```
triggerBody()?['key-button-date']
```

A quick explanation ...

1. `triggerBody()` retrieves the content of the `body` object in the json.
2. The question mark `?` indicates that it will not error if the child property you're requesting does not exist.  The question mark is not mandatory.
3. This is where it gets the child property and the name of that property, as you can see, is `key-button-date`.

If the JSON was nested further, you just keep going, e.g. ...

```
triggerBody()?['key-button-date']?['Example 1']?['Example 2']
```

[image: Key Button Date]

This may help to explain further ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#expressions